# update content at runtime WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, runtime

I would like to be able to display some property changes at runtime, and I don't know how to do it. I am learning binding, and the following example works fine, but I want be able to monitor the changes of the binded properties at runtime.

I have a class Player:

```
class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string id;
    public string ID { get => id; }

    private int power;
    public int Power
    {
        get => power;
        set
        {
            if (this.power != value)
            {
                this.power = value;
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Power");
            }
        }
    }


    public Player(string playerId)
    {
        id = playerId;
        power = 50;
    }
}
```

I create some number of players, who fight against each other and earn or lose power. Using data binding I display all players id's and power points in a ListView, and histogram of their power points distribution, using Polygon:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static readonly Random random = new Random();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Player> players;

        private PointCollection powerHistogramPoints;
        public PointCollection PowerHistogramPoints
        {
            get => this.powerHistogramPoints;
            set
            {
                if (this.powerHistogramPoints != value)
                {
                    this.powerHistogramPoints = value;
                    if (this.PropertyChanged != null) this.NotifyPropertyChanged("PowerHistogramPoints");
                }
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            players = new ObservableCollection<Player> { };
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) players.Add(new Player("player" + i.ToString("D3")));
            popListView.ItemsSource = players;
            CreateHistogram();
        }

        private void runButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunEpochs(Int32.Parse(nEpochsTextBox.Text));
            CreateHistogram();
        }

        private int[] CreateHistogram(...){...}

        internal void RunEpochs(int nEpochs)
        {for (int i = 0; i < nEpochs; i++) RunEpoch();}
        private void RunEpoch(){...}
    }
```

and xaml code is:

```
        <ListView Margin="2" Name="popListView">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="player ID" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="power" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Power}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

and

```
           <GroupBox Height="200" Width="300" Header="Power Distribution" BorderThickness="0">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" Margin="4">
                    <Polygon Points="{Binding PowerHistogramPoints}" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Opacity="0.8" />
                </Border>
            </GroupBox>
```

I have controls that allow me to chose how many epochs to run, and after they run, both the listview and the histogram update nicely. But I want to be able to run, say one million epochs, and to be able to monitor the changes in the player points and histogram in real time (for example, update the list and the graph every 1000 epochs, or every second, etc..) What changes to the above code should I do?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the calls to NotifyPropertyChanged from the properties Setters,

And call them manually after your Timer hits your set ElapsedTime.

The Timer can be in a background work thread and do all the notifying inside a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke block.